# RethinkDB Unhandled Rejection No stack trace

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb, rethinkdbdash

I'm using RethinkDB with Rethinkdbdash (node.js) and for a few days now Im getting this error:

```
Unhandled rejection (<[{"entries":3,"id":1357186,"item":{"co...>, no stack trace)
```

Doesn't matter what query do I run, when i try to get any info from the database I always get the same error. If nothing is returned, error looks like this:

```
Unhandled rejection (<(empty array)>, no stack trace)
```

This is my current code:

```
     r.table('example').run().then(function(err, result){
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
    })
```

Comment: maybe you want to post your full code, with connection initialization and so.

Comment: There is no connection initialization. As I mentioned, I use RethinkDBDash, so the only code is ```const r = require('rethinkdbdash')(config.db);```

Comment: I also want to mention that inserting and pulling works, but it returns this as a response.

Comment: i am not particularly familiar with RethinkDBdash, but isn't this how it supposed to work? : r.table('example').run().then(function(result){
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(err){
       console.log(err);
    }

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help my case

Answer (score 0):

You would need to include the `database: 'databasename'` field in the config object and pass the config object into run, otherwise you could try to specify the db in your ReQL query.

Specify db for connection:

```js
let connection = null
r.connect( { host: 'localhost', port: 28015, user: 'user', password: 'password', database: 'databasename'}, function(err, conn) {
    if (err) throw err
    else {
      connection = conn
      r.table('example').run(connection, function(err, result){
        if(err) throw err;
        else console.log(`${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
      })
    }    
})
```

Specify db in query:

```js
let connection = null
r.connect( { host: 'localhost', port: 28015, user: 'user', password: 'password'}, function(err, conn) {
    if (err) throw err
    else {
      connection = conn
      r.db('databasename').table('example').run(connection, function(err, result){
        if(err) throw err;
        else console.log(`${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
      })
    }    
})
```